# android system server to cache application data

Tags: android, android-framework

I am working on a android framework. I implemented an system server which works fine, i.e., a sample application can communicate with the service. Now i want my server to be able to read and write data into a file or sqlite like database. I am pretty new to android framework development so i am not sure how this works. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In what language will you write your server? If in Java, put the "Java" tag on your question. If in php, put the "PHP" tag on your question. etc.

Comment: I am not sure you are following . I wrote an aidl interface to implement a system service and then wrote java code to support it. We are talking android framework here its mostly java and especially not php .

Comment: Ah, you have built an android service. to me, "server" means a server, not a service.

Answer (score 1):

To handle database in Android (to store some apps/service data) you should use ContentProviders class.

There is a great tutorial on developer.android.com pages:
Content Providers
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html
and its subchapters:

- Content Provider Basics (how to use already exising Android database)
- Creating a Content Provider (how to create new sql database and simple interface to access it)

There is also Note Pad sample application in android SDK samples (on harddrive /samples/android-/  - http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html). Please take a look at class NotePadProvider (com.example.android.notepad) in this sample app.

BR
Paweł Rutkowski

PS. I think that this question was not answered for so long because title is misleading - it should more about storing user/app configuration in Android or about using sql database in Android.

Comment: Thanks. for the reply. But i believe the question was straight forward. I was not talking about how to do this on android application (or services within the application). The question was how to modify or handle this in android OS itself.Thanks for help anyway

Comment: I am confused by your comment - are you looking for method of modyfing Sqlite database from Android user perspective (so some apps for Android?), Or you are looking for method to modify database externally (by modyfing file on file system)? If it is second case you cane use tool sqlite3, provided with Android SDK (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#sqlite) - it is using standard SQL syntax. Anyway, from your answer I suspect that you already solved this issue ... if that is the case please provide your answer

Comment: nop.. Well its a very old question. i have already did it and published 2 papers on the same since then :) .I figured out the way. The original idea was to write a system service which should be able to write in an sql database. In one of the other thread i learnt that one can use any other services/resources the way we use in applications.  Thanks for the help though. It was really important for my research. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Using the standard android sqlite database in a service is identical to using it from an activity. The android documentation and the samples show you how to do that.